# selecting multiple indexes for listboxes in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, listbox

So i have a list box which contains two values A and B. The list box has the selection mode set to MultiSimple i.e. both A and B can be selected. I basically want to trigger some code if both values are selected but cant find a way. I've tried...

```
if (lstFunctions.SelectedIndex == 0 && lstFunction.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            // do something!
        }
```

This however doesn't work. It seems simple in theory but i just cant figure it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think looping over the `ListBox` items and checking the `Selected` property would work.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(lstFunctions.Items[0].Selected && lstFunctions.Items[1].Selected)
{
}
```

This code gets first and second item in the listbox collection and checks if both are selected.

Comment: hmm its not liking the .Selected. object does not contain a definition for Selected.

Comment: @ArvidBoome This is how my ListBox is made and it works.
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:ListBox>